# How to copy values untill last row

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to copy "D7:O10" in excel untill lastrow in column "C".

It kinda works but the code paste only D7:O7 untill last row.

I think i need some kind of offset.

```
Sub CopyFormulae()

Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

i = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D7:O10" & i).FillDown

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Range("D7:O10" & i) will be Range(D7:D109") in your code.  That only fills down with the first cell formula.

Comment: Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: @sjr what do you mean with starting on C1? If last row is not muliple of 4 i dont know what happens. Im a noob :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change This

```
Range("D7:O10" & i).FillDown
```

To

```
Range("D7:O10").Copy
begin = 7
Do While begin < i
    Range("D" & begin).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    begin = begin + 4

Loop
```

Comment: WOOOW! THIS WORKED PERFECT!